# Why would this answer be voted down?

Tags: discussion, support, voting

[Two dogmas of empiricism - logical vs analytic truths... is there really a distinction?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/72120/two-dogmas-of-empiricism-logical-vs-analytic-truths-is-there-really-a-disti/72757#72757)

Answer (score 1):

Because it simply does not answer the question as asked. The question asks for an explanation of the reasoning of Quine and the extent of consequences following out of it.

Your answer states some things about logic as if they were angelic gospel and not up to debate - something which Quine points out as being nonsensical - and thereby allegedly rejects Quine.

Doing this without even trying to understand and explain the reasoning in question both means that this is not an answer to the question and would be considered bad conduct in philosophical discourse since it transports a maxim of "I know better, you (or this guy, respectively) know(s) nothing".

Comment: It seems to me that you are not realizing that this question is only focusing on the aspect of Quine's paper that Quine himself already acknowledged is a logical certainty: "No unmarried man is married."

Comment: A direct quote from Quine's paper: >>>(1) No unmarried man is married.
The relevant feature of this example is that it is not merely true as it stands, but remains true under any and all reinterpretations of 'man' and 'married.'<<<